# php7 compatibility: Uncaught Exception: Error

Tags: php, php-7

can you help me update this script for compatibility with php7? I get error: Uncaught Exception: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

```
$qry = "SELECT oo.`value` FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_option AS oo INNER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value AS pov ON (oo.product_option_id = pov.product_option_id AND oo.product_option_value_id = pov.product_option_value_id) WHERE oo.order_id = '".$order_id."' AND oo.order_product_id = '".$order_product_id."' AND pov.option_id IN (".implode(",", $this->config->get('glami_size_options')).")";
```

Comment: Have you printed that string to see what it actually looks like?  Was your DB_PREFIX defined as a constant?  How?

Comment: That error message isn't from PHP, it's from your database; PHP is just reporting it to you. You'll need to look at the SQL you've generated, and find the syntax error. While you're working on it, you could start [using parameterized queries, to protect from SQL Injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/157957).

Comment: Are you sure that `$this->config->get('glami_size_options')` always contains data? Otherwise, the query will fail.

Comment: There's nothing here which is obviously incompatible with PHP7. And as others have mentiond, the error is clearly a SQL error, not a PHP error, anyway.